# Way to serve a "public" folder in github pages

Tags: github

I have personal blog in github repo **myname.github.io**, i generates my site contents using **Cabin** site generator which generate build files in **public** folder. I wanted to serve the contents from **public** folder for **Github** pages. But it is always looking at the root folder.

Is there any option to tell *Github* to serve contents from **public** folder, not from root folder?

Comment: If nothing else works, you could just set up an index.html in the root that uses JavaScript to redirect the browser.

Comment: What you mean by redirect?

Comment: if you set `window.location` to some value in JavaScript, I believe it ought to load whatever page you set the new location to. (eg `window.location = "google.com"` "redirects" the page to Google)

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove the dist directory from the project’s `.gitignore file` (it’s ignored by default by Yeoman).
2. Make sure git knows about your subtree (the subfolder with your site).
   `git add dist && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"`
3. Use `subtree push` to send it to the gh-pages branch on GitHub.
   `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`
   Source: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490
4. Go to the settings of the project and set the gh-pages as the branch 
           for the website